# How to configure VS2022 to Get Output from Fine Code Coverage Plug-in

Tags: code-coverage, visual-studio-2022

I installed FCC into Visual Studio 2022.  My project is a C++ project using GoogleTest.  When I run the tests there is no output generated. In the FCC output screen I get the following messages:
"A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
No test is available in C:\Repos\c-_course\SWTimers\x64\Debug\fine-code-coverage\build-output\TestSwTimers.exe. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Additionally, path to test adapters can be specified using /TestAdapterPath command. Example  /TestAdapterPath:.
Committing...
No results, this could be for a number of reasons. The most common reasons are:
1) missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter please review the
output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf) about filters.
2) the profiler may not be registered correctly, please refer to the Usage
guide and the -register switch.
Fine Code Coverage 1/29/2024 2:42:24 PM: Completed coverage for (TestSwTimers) : 00:00:18.5982205"

In the fine-code-coverage/build-output/ I find the executables for both SWTimers.exe(source to test) and TestSwTimers.exe as well as the SWTimers.pdb and Gtest.pdb.  The tests all run successfully.

I could not find the Usage guide.  I have no idea how to verify the other items mentioned in the error messages.  Any help would be appreciated.

Have searched for the usage.rtf file to no avail, verified that  the output exes and pdbs exist is the fine-code-coverage/build-output